# Eclipse Juno (4.2.1) crashes frequently after upgrading to Ubuntu12.10 from 12.04 (both 64bits)?

Tags: 64-bit, 12.10, eclipse

I was using eclipse Juno (ver 4.2.1) on my 64bit ubuntu 12.04 for almost a month or more. It was working perfectly and I really enjoyed working on it.

However two days back I upgraded my machine to Ubuntu 12.10 since than eclipse Juno is working strangely irritating. It crashes frequently. I even removed the old installation completely and reinstalled everything (ADT, Subclipse, CDT etc.)

What could be the possible reason behind this ? How I solve it ?

Comment: Thanks - I found this provids stability running Kepler SR2 on Ubuntu 14.04 using Oracle JDK 1.7.0.55.
Without -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla eclipse was crashing frequently.

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrading from 12:04 to 14:04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have similar problem with my Ubuntu 12.10 and Eclipse Juno 4.2.

So every now and then, when I switch between applications, my Eclipse crashes. It simply closes itself with some error screen with a lot's of gtk libs mentioned. I've got info screen that this crash report will be sent for further analysis.

Then I've search on the net, and found this bug report in eclipse:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382812

Following this bug, at the end you will find that it is confirmed on:
Eclipse SDK 4.2.0

And it will be solved in Eclipse 4.3.

One of possible solution is to download latest Eclipse nightly buid, but I've switched back to Eclipse Indigo and will wait for official Eclipse 4.3

Answer (score 10):

After many many permutations of everything, including all the different JDKs, etc., etc. ..

This worked for me (Fedora19/64, ADT 4.3/SDK 22.x,OpenJDK 1.8, Opteron64): add this line to the eclipse.ini file:

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

Apparently the tooltip bits launch different browsers at different times with "collisions", but restricting to mozilla only seems to do the trick

<sup>**Source:** https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1163501</sup>

Comment: I think you saved my day! This seems to fix the problem I was having with eclipse sincve I switched to Trusty... Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did this, crashes less often, but still does

Comment: it worked for me eclipse juno 4.2

Answer (score 2):

Try to paste the following line inside `configuration>config.ini`

```
org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, post upgrade eclipse started crashing. I removed Eclipse Juno(4.2) and installed eclipse from software centre (v 3.8).

Comment: Did all your programs crashes same time or it is just the eclipse Juno ? In my case after freeze of few seconds the title bar of all the application disappears. Leaving a dirty desktop with no mouse / keyboard working. this is really annoying ? please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Install Oracle JDK instead of Open JDK from here http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

I tried installing Eclipse Juno (SR1, SR2) , Eclipse classic, Eclipse Indigo SR2, Old Eclipse classic. Each one crashed like hell on Ubuntu 12.10. Finally after installing Oracle JDK, it stopped crashing (using Indigo SR2)

PS : Its still crashing few times but much better than before.
It especially crashes while using tomcat. Hence while coding, modify your application as Java Desktop Application using (main function temporarily) and finally when everything is done, run it as web application by removing main function.