# XPCOM error 0x80004005 with RTC 4.0.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, eclipse, rtc

I had a problem when I start Rational Team Concert 4.0.6 which is installed on Rational Software Architect 9.1.2 (eclipse 4.2) on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

I also had the same problem as described by this defect
[JVM Terminated. Exit Code=160 when submitting build in RTC Eclipse elient](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/104317/jvm-terminated-exit-code160-when-submitting-build-in-rtc-eclipse-elient)

**I tried the following solutions:**

the [Eclipse Juno (4.2.1) crashes frequently after upgrading to Ubuntu12.10 from 12.04 (both 64bits)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206182/eclipse-juno-4-2-1-crashes-frequently-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu12-10-from-12-0) question

This didn't work with me

Comment: I also tried the solution as the [Running IBM Data Studio 4.1.01 on Ubuntu 14.04] ([3]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/455685/running-ibm-data-studio-4-1-01-on-ubuntu-14-04) and it didn't work with me

Comment: I also tried to install Xulrunner as follows:  1. As per the question [How do I install xulrunner?][http://askubuntu.com/questions/125980/how-do-i-install-xulrunner] 2. from which I identified the needed xulrunner version to be installed from [What do I need to run the SWT Browser inside Eclipse on Linux?][http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux] 3. then I downloaded and installed it [XULRunner 1.9.2 Release Notes][https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner/1.9.2] 

Again this didn't help with my configuration listed above.

Answer (score 1):

The solution came finally but on pieces so I am not sure if one piece is only needed or all of them but I will list them all here.

1. Make sure you have a 64 bit version of Xulrunner. The version that worked with me is 1.9.2.13 and you can downland the file [xulrunner-1.9.2.13.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/nightly/2010/12/2010-12-01-03-mozilla-1.9.2/xulrunner-1.9.2.13.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2). extract it to /opt/ and this will create a new folder "/opt/xulrunner"
2. Add the following parameters in the eclipse.ini. I think from my trials that the first part only is enough. However, when it works I was not interested to continue to test it :). Please note that "/opt/xulrunner" is the folder path, not the application

   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/opt/xulrunner
3. The last item when I think it is mandatory and it is coming from this [article](https://jazz.net/library/article/1337). The crash is caused by a bug in the GTK theme, which is the default theme selection in Window->Preferences->General->Appearance.  To fix that you must change the theme selection from the default setting to the "Classic" setting

Comment: This fixed it for me on RHEL 7.2